HAProxy - Keep path in url - acl
All.
I have the following configuration file:
frontend devopsdb
  bind    *:8080
  acl grafana_path path_beg /grafana/
  use_backend back_grafana if grafana_path 

backend back_grafana
  server grafana-dev 10.152.183.155:80 


What I need is that when I access the url (172.21.10.76 is my test VM and where HAProxy is): http://172.21.10.76:8080/grafana/
it is redirected to the grafana POD: 10.152.183.155:80
So far so good, it works.
But as soon as it is redirected, the path /grafana/ disappears from the URL and that's why HAProxy stops redirecting... - http://172.21.10.76:8080/login
Is it possible to keep /grafana/ somehow by HAProxy?
The same will happen with another POD /prometheus/

The problem here is that your backend (grafana) doesn't know anything about the path prefix, so when it generates urls, they will be relative to / (so, /login, /api, etc).
You need to tell grafana that it's hosted at a path other than /. You can do this with the root_url and serve_from_subpath configuration settings (documented in "Running Grafana behind a reverse proxy").
Running grafana from a compose file, that might look like this:
volumes:
  grafana-data:

services:
  haproxy:
    image: docker.io/haproxy:lts
    volumes:
      - ./haproxy.cfg:/usr/local/etc/haproxy/haproxy.cfg
    ports:
    - "8888:8080"

  grafana:
    image: docker.io/grafana/grafana:11.3.1
    volumes:
    - "grafana-data:/var/lib/grafana"
    environment:
      GF_SERVER_DOMAIN: localhost
      GF_SERVER_ROOT_URL: "%(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/"
      GF_SERVER_SERVE_FROM_SUB_PATH: "true"

Alternately, you can configure things in your grafana.ini file:
[server]
domain = localhost
root_url = %(protocol)s://%(domain)s:%(http_port)s/grafana/
serve_from_sub_path = true

From the documentation I didn't think serve_from_subpath would be necessary, but without that I end up with a redirect loop.

Thanks! If it's on the services side, I need to solve it another way then... It was supposed to be quick, but it looks like I'll have to use DNS anyway.
